# Yii update profile page

Tags: php, yii

i created a update profile page.

i have this in the controller to populate the form and also handle update:

```
$user = User::model()->findByPk(Yii::app()->user->id);
// Collect user input 
if (isset($_POST['User'])) {
 $user->attributes = $_POST['User'];

 if ($user->save()) {
  echo "update successfully";
 }
 else {
  echo "update failed";
 }
}

// View
$this->render('user_view', array('user'=>$user,));
```

however, this doesn't work. although $user->save is true, the record is not updated in the database. i've also check that $_POST['User'] is returning the updated data but $user->attributes is not saving them.

why is that so?

Comment: i can assign manually using $user->name= $_POST['User']['name']; but this would be troublesome if there's a list of data to update

Comment: check out thaddeusmt's answer, would be great if you could also post your 'User' model :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set which model attributes are "safe" for "massive assignments". Read more about this [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.model#safe-attributes-in-1-1).

The mass attribute assignment `$user->attributes` will only assign to variables with validation rules. Just give the `name` attribute a rule, even if it's just the ["safe" validator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CSafeValidator).

```
public function rules()
{
  return array(
    array('name', 'safe')
  );
}
```

I'm pretty sure this is the problem you are having, it's happened to me!

Comment: Most likely this is indeed the problem, I ran into it myself already a bunch of times :)